# arithmetic syntax error in UNIX

Tags: linux, unix

this variable is getting a string value.. i am not able to do any arithmetic operation on it.

Consider a file below -

> abc. txt

i took it into variable.. A

> A=abc.txt

it has one record as below -

> TLR|12345
>
> variable=$(grep -i ^TLR ${A}  | cut - d'|' -f2 | awk '{print $1}')

this variable is getting a string value.. i am not able to do any arithmetic operation on it.

pls advise how can i do.

Comment: i have already tried to use :expr to try to change it to integer.. also have tried to trim the whitespaces.. but nothing is helping out

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are writing a bash script, you could use something like the following:

```
A=abc.txt
variable=$(grep -i ^TLR ${A} | cut -d'|' -f2)
echo $variable;

# Use the $((...)) syntax:
variable2=$((variable + 5))
echo $variable2

# Call the external expr program:
variable3=`expr $variable + 5`
echo $variable3
```

The solution to your problem is likely on line 6: in order to perform arithmetic operations on a variable, you use the `$((...))` syntax; in the example, it adds `5` to the existing `variable`. The output of the example should be:

```
12345
12350
12350
```

On line 10, an alternative solution is provided which calls the expernal `expr` program.

See [this webpage](https://www.shell-tips.com/2010/06/14/performing-math-calculation-in-bash/) for some more examples on arithmetic expressions in bash scripts.

Comment: hi ngj,  thank for your answer.. i have tried this but it is nit working.. neither in bash nor in ksh..

Comment: Can you post the exact command which is not working? (the code I have pasted works correctly in bash, so maybe there is a small typo somewhere. note that, in your original post, there is already a type in `cut - d` which should be corrected to `cut -d`)

Comment: var7=$((variable + 5))
var7=$(($variable + 5))
var7=$(("$variable" + 5))

believe me i have tried all three.. there is no typo..

Comment: All three arithmetic expressions you provide seem to work here, although the first one is the recommended syntax. I have edited my answer to provide an alternative approach, which calls the external `expr` program instead of using the `$((...))` syntax. Is there anything special about the environment in which you are running the script? Are you 100% sure that `$variable` contains only digits?

Comment: By the way, you can also remove the pipe from `cut` to `awk`, as shown in my answer code, which may simplify looking for a solution.